# A volunteer coordinator has 30 identical chocolate chip cookies to distribute to six volunteers.

Tags: generating-functions

Use a generating function (and computer algebra system) to determine the number of ways she can distribute the cookies so that each volunteer receives at least two cookies and no more than seven cookies.

I don't know how to do generating functions. Can someone explain the concept and help me apply it to this situation?

Comment: It seems like asking too much for someone to explain generating functions and tell you how to use it for the given situation. Are you completely unfamiliar with generating functions, or do you have at least some background? It seems odd that you'd have this question if you know nothing about them.

Comment: I've read the text in my textbook, but I don't think I understand how it works.

Answer (score 1):

$(x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7)^6$

The coefficient of $x^{30}$ is 3431.